# LNK2019 problem

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I have a [LNK2019](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/799kze2z%28VS.80%29.aspx) problem when trying to use some DLL in my project.

Details:

1. I have a DLL project called dll1; that compiled just fine (using `__declspec(dllexport)`) in order to export the class inside dll1 (for dll2 usage).
2. I have another DLL project dll2 that uses dll1's functionality.  I specified the *.dll1.lib file path inside the linker input in the project's properties and gave reference to dll1 *.h files.  At this point everything needs to work fine.  (I think..)
3. When compiling dll2, I get a LNK2019 error that tells me can't find some method referenced in dll1.  (This method in dll1 is a static method.)

Why do I get this error?

Comment: are you using any static variable inside the static method?

Comment: As an idea. Ii might be useful to use Depends. Run it, open you dll1, check "View/Undecorated C++ Funcitons", find your function in the list of functions and methods and check that it has exactly the same number of args and it is in the correct namespace.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [MSDN page about LNK2019](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/799kze2z%28VS.80%29.aspx) already gives plenty of examples why this error occurs. In order to trace down what exactly is going on, I recommend doing this:

1. Run `undname` on the symbol which the linker complains about to demangle the name (see [Viewing Decorated Names](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5x49w699.aspx) for an example how to run `undname`).
2. Run `dumpbin /EXPORTS` (or use the graphical [Dependency Walker](http://dependencywalker.com/)) to get a list of all symbols exported by DLL1.

So now you have the demangled name of the symbol which the linker tries to find, and you have the list of symbols which are exported by DLL1. And the linker tells you that it cannot find the requested symbol in the list. Here are two ideas about what's going on:

1. You see that DLL1 has the demangled symbol in its export list, but not exactly the mangled name which the linker complains about. This can happen when the function you export is *almost* the same which the linker expects. It might be that you have a 'const' missing somewhere, or the calling convention is different.
2. You see that DLL1 doesn't export any symbol which looks like what the linker expects. This suggests that some `__declspec(dllexport)` is missing in the declarations of DLL1.

Comment: Is it possible to do something similar when the target library is a LIB rather than a DLL? Dumpbin won't run on static libraries, and when I try dependency walker on mine I get a "no signature" error.

Answer (score 2):

For regular static class methods the declspec(dllexport) should be sufficient but in some cases (inline friend functions for example) you need to provide declspec(dllexport) for the function.

e.g.

```
#define DLLEXPORT __declspec(dllexport) 

class DLLEXPORT A {


     A();

     int somefunc();

     DLLEXPORT friend int operator==(const A &ws1, const A &ws2) 
            { /* some code */ } 

};
```

Answer (score 1):

**Just a guess:**

If you include the header from **dll1** in the **dll2** project and in that header you use the `__declspec(dllexport))` you tell the linker that **dll2** is also exporting these classes that actually are meant to be imported by **dll2** and so is missing classes definition.

So one would ususally use a definition like this.

```
#ifdef DLL1_EXPORTS
#define DLLEXPORT __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define DLLEXPORT __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

class DLLEXPORT A
{
    //...
```

This construction makes sure, the **dll1** definitions are exported when the header is used in **dll1** and imported when used inside **dll2** project. All you need is the macro `DLL1_EXPORT` to be defined when **dll1** is compiled. The project settings for **dll1** is usually a good place.

Another approach is to have 2 different headers, one for building **dll1** and a second to be used together wit **dll1**'s lib (without any `__declspec(dllexport)`).

Answer (score 0):

I recently had the same problem. The problem was a method signature `void myMethod(const MyType&);`with a parameter which I had forward-declared as `class MyType;`; however, the definition was a `struct MyType{};`.

As described in https://stackoverflow.com/a/40738415/71051 this can lead to linker issues with Visual-C++ - in my case the LNK2019.

Took me a while to resolve this, maybe this is of help for someone in the future.