# Is this equivalent to a std::string?

Tags: c++, string, stl, linker, std

Trying to track down a LNK2019 Unresolved External Symbol error on a function that has a number of `std::string const &` arguments.

Step one of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1763480/lnk2019-problem/1763671#1763671) says to check decorated / undecorated names, and this is what I'm seeing in the linker error text in the argument list:

```
class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &
```

Is this also `std::string const &`  ?

Thanks for your help.

I'm running VS 2008.

Comment: Check out the typedef for 'string' [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hd5zecz6(v=VS.100).aspx):  `typedef basic_string<char> string` and notice the default values for the `Traits` and `Allocator` parameters to the basic_string template

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes.

As part of the C++ standardization, the `std::string` class was made more STL-compatible. Like the STL containers, the element type can be chosen. Common choices are `char` and `wchar_t`, but Visual C++ users can also use `TCHAR`. Like STL containers, memory allocation is handled by an allocator.

However, strings are unlike other containers because some methods need to perform more complex operations on their elements. `std::set<T>` only needs to compare two `T` objects, but `std::string` needs to deal with multi-byte encodings and such complications. These details are wrapped up in class `std::char_traits<char>`.

So, with all this complexity, you end up with `std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >`. That's of course not very friendly, and most people just need the defaults. `std::string` is the friendly name for that.

Comment: Very helpful MSalters.  Thank you!