# Forward declaration as struct vs class

Tags: c++, struct, forward-declaration

I found a mistake in a C++ forward declaration of a class, which was wrongly declared as `struct Book` instead of `class Book`. I think Book used to be a struct, got changed to a class but the forward declarations remained.

Book.h:

```
class Book {
    ...
};
```

Library.h:

```
struct Book;

class Library {
    std::vector<Book*> books;
};
```

There were no compiler warnings and the resulting program seemed to work fine. It made me curious: **in theory, can this ever cause a problem?** It's just a pointer, yes, but for example, if the class had virtual methods, multiple inheritance, could the pointers be different?

I know the differences between class/struct regarding default public/private but I'm asking specifically about the forward declarations and possible consequences of swapping them.

**UPDATE** newer versions of Xcode now give this warning when there's a mismatch:

```
Struct 'Book' was previously declared as a class; this is valid, but may result in linker errors under the Microsoft C++ ABI
```

Comment: It is not a mistake in C++, but VS might give you some grief.

Comment: @Danh edited question to explain the difference.

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4866425/mixing-class-and-struct

Answer (score 35, accepted):

`struct` and `class` are completely interchangeable as far as forward declarations are concerned. Even for definitions, they only affect the default access specifier of the objects members, everything else is equivalent. You always define "classes" of objects.

The only place where `struct` must be used over `class`, is when forward declaring opaque data for [c](/questions/tagged/c) bindings.

---

Regarding your edit:

> I know the differences between class/struct regarding default public/private but I'm asking specifically about the forward declarations and possible consequences of swapping them.

Visual C++ produces warning [C4099](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/695x5bes.aspx). It does it, because the name decoration for its functions incorporates the keyword you used. Therefore, programs *may* fail to link properly. So perfectly standard compliant code may not link when using VC++ (A bonehead move on Microsoft's part, AFAIC).

A discussion of this warning, as well as why it can be ignored if you are disciplined, can be found [here](https://alfps.wordpress.com/2010/06/22/cppx-is-c4099-really-a-sillywarning-disabling-msvc-sillywarnings/)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. For peace of mind and to avoid any compiler quirks and possible future psychopathic maintainers' wrath, I will make all the forward declarations match.

Comment: That behaviour is what I needed for my current task. I need to make forward declaration on a type passed as template parameter or macro parameter but the passed type can be a class or struct.

Comment: This can indeed cause linker errors in VC++. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33483623/visual-c-2015-linker-error-when-forward-declaring-a-struct-as-class

Comment: Re. "A bonehead move on Microsoft's part" In C4099 documentation it explicitly says the MSVC compiler will correct you and always use the **definition** over the **declaration**. It is warning you because ***another*** compiler is free to not do this.